# Can there be more buttons in the suggested edit queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, flags

Sometimes when I'm reading a Suggested Edit, I believe that the question/answer is really awful and not particularly salvageable. Usually when this happens, the edited form of the post is an improvement, but the post itself is still *too localized*, *not an answer*, etc. In these situations I often say to myself "Okay, that helped, but..."

To be clear: the edit itself is fine, but the original post still doesn't have enough quality content even after the edit.

So my request: Can we add a button "Flag original post" that brings up the standard flag window?

Corollary question: Even if we don't add such a button, what is the recommended course of action in this situation - open the post in its own window, then flag it there? I suppose, if that's the case, doing that is easy enough that we don't **need** a button, but it would be nice to have.

---

Part of the reason I ask the question is that I want to know if an edit that makes a question go from *downright awful* to *pretty bad* should be Accepted? But it's also a situation where "Improve" wouldn't help either, because there's nothing to be done. Should we Accept, then Flag? Or Skip->Flag? Accept->Downvote? Case by case?

Comment: Even more buttons? What's wrong with clicking through and flagging via the question? In that way, you are also "forced" to judge the quality by seeing existing replies (answeres / comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a question that deserves to be closed, click through to the question and vote to close it. That's not the purpose of the suggested edits queue. You're there to review the validity of *edits*, not the content of the question itself. Voting to close a question ultimately has nothing to do with the edit you were presented - it still needs to be approved, rejected, or improved. A "Close" action doesn't put it any closer to being reviewed.

Comment: I added another part to the question.

Comment: See [Is “don't polish turds” a valid edit rejection reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason) and [How should I deal with suggested edits to terrible questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128770/how-should-i-deal-with-suggested-edits-to-terrible-questions) and [Should I bother to edit questions that will be closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130066/should-i-bother-to-edit-questions-that-will-be-closed) - But in the end it's up to you.

Comment: That first one didn't come up in my searching. If it had, I wouldn't have made this question. Thanks